# what is implementation type in java

Tags: java, types

I'm new to Java. I have came across a term called "implementation type" during my reading. I was just wondering what exactly does implementation type refers to?

```
Person person = new Person(); //Person class is the implementation type
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();//HashSet class is the implementation type
```

So is my interpretation of what is the implementation type for the above two statements correct? If not, could someone please correct me? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Rishi `Set` isn't an implementation; `Set` is an interface, `HashSet` is an implementation of the `Set` interface

Comment: @beresfordt You are right, I will edit my comment

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the book is using the word implementation type, when refering to the object type.

In your examples, you have your pointers (person, stringSet), and you have your objects created.

Take:

```
Person cavani= new Person();
```

The right side of this statement ( splited by the =) is the object creation. You are creating a new object of type Person (this type is the implementation type, infered from your examples). The left side is your pointer, which you use to make reference to your newly Person created. In this case your name for this pointer is cavani.

cavani pointer could've been other type of pointer like for example HumanBeing.
If HumanBeing is a class , and Person is a subclass, your pointer can be of the type HumanBeing, and still point it to the new Person. Because Person inherits HumanBeing class.